# Can't get PidTagBody (0x1000) value via Office 365 EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, managed-ews

PR_BODY is never returned by EWS (using Office 365 server)

```
PropertySet properties = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BODY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1000, MapiPropertyType.String);
properties.Add(PR_BODY);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, properties);
```

There is no body (0x1000) value in the server response. At the same time, if I change

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BODY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1000, MapiPropertyType.String);
```

to

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BODY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1000, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
```

I start getting exception and response code is ErrorInvalidExtendedProperty. This does not happen if I pass property id not known to EWS (like 0x1990). So EWS understands which type 0x1000 should have but still doesn't return anything when the type is correct.

BTW, this works for PR_BODY_HTML:

```
PropertySet properties = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BODY_HTML = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1013, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
properties.Add(PR_BODY_HTML);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, properties);
```

Actually, I can get plain-text body with the code like

```
properties.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
properties.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Body);
```

Or with:

```
properties.Add(ItemSchema.TextBody);
```

But I'm wondering why it doesn't work via extended properties (and at the same time this works for HTML body).

Finally, when trying the same with my local Exchange 2010 server, I found that PR_BODY is returned just fine. Is it a bug of Office 365 service?